# JCheckBox trouble

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox

I have a next problem with Java GUI.

On my computer I see my application like this:

**Normal picture**

[image: Normal picture]

But I have another machine where I see this:

**Problematic picture**

[image: Problematic picture]

I don't understand why it happens.
Can anyone explain?

I have Windows 7 Professional on both machine with jdk1.7.0_09.

Comment: Looks like a layout issue, but without sample code it's impossible to tell

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This gui was created with windowBuilder.

Comment: *"This gui was created with windowBuilder."*  What is that supposed to mean?  It uses null layouts?  You cannot find the code? ..

Comment: It's 2000  lines of automatic generated code. I have about 200 computers that use this program and it first time that i see this problem.

Comment: Remove 1950 lines of code or till the problem disappears, in which case you'll have narrowed down the problem, or have an SSCCE.  Good luck!

Comment: Make a new program with just one JCheckBox and try it on a healthy machine and then on the one that causes you the trouble. Could be that something is wrong with the JVM on this machine.

Comment: I will do it. But I tried to re-install a JVM. It's not help.

Comment: Actually, I reckon this has nothing to do directly with your Java programme. Instead, I think it's that the Windows machine has got some default font settings adjusted. Java is picking up the adjusted font and running with it. This link may help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller

Comment: That's exactly why you shouldn't ever use a GUI builder. As long as everything is fine, no problem. If something is not ok, you will have to search through thousands of lines of bad-formatted and unreadable code. Well, in this case, this might not be a Java related problem. But do you see my point?..

Comment: **Also:** Is your problem the different font that is used, or that there are no checkboxes displayed on the "bad" machine? From the second screenshot, I can not really tell, if there are checkboxes on the right, because it is cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me.

Right click on 'Desktop', select properties and on the display settings
change the display size to `100%` (default) and this should solve the problem on the specific machine.

Comment: *"Change the display size to 100% (default) and this should.."* hide *"..the problem.."*  ..at least until the 3rd machine.  -1, terrible answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.. this **does** solve the problem. I'm telling him to do what I did and what silved my problem. If he understood what my answer is, and if it does solve his problem, I don't think your comment was necessary. Furthermore, instead of using words such as "terrible", you can be more gentle and point to the problem. We are here to learn and to help each other. Picking good words can change many things :) Salam.

Comment: 1) It does not solve the problem, since the display size can be different on each new machine. 2) The actual solution is to be found in layouts, as suggested over two hours prior to this answer. 3) You did not like 'terrible'?  Try woeful, deplorable, execrable, woebegone, creaky, flea-bitten, derelict, run-down, miserable, decrepit or wretched instead.  There is no way to paint bad advice in 'nice words'.  Your advice sucked.  Learn & move on (is my advice).

Comment: 1) Since he said the problem was only on one machine, this solution was suggested to this specific machine. 3) probably you don't know better words.. it's a matter of education.. oh.. and there is a way to point bad advice in """""nice words""""".. if I had time I would teach you some, maybe bext time. This solved his problem, and your wisdom doesn't help him here.. now move on to the next person you want to show him how much terrible/misrable.. (you know more words).. he is

Comment: 1) *"Since he said the problem was only on **one** machine"* Wrong, the OP stated *"**another** machine"*.  What, you think this app. is only ever to be run on 2 machines?  3) *"if I had time I would teach you some"*  If I had time I'd spend it doing more useful things.

Comment: Anyway, it solved the OP problem (when we spoke on chat he said it was **only on one machine..**), I took you comment into considiration and I hope we'll end this conversation in a good spirit :) sorry if I misunderstood you.. have a great weekend! :)